# sql query select for boolean

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables **answers**, **questions** and **users** and i have **joined** them all to get result that i am getting

```
SELECT answers.answer_content as answer_content,
       answers.id as answer_id,
       answers.created_at as created_at,
       questions.id as question_id, 
       questions.question_title as question_title, 
       questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
       users.id as user_id, 
       users.name as user_name, 
       users.user_slug as user_slug,
                                  FROM answers
                                          JOIN questions
                                               on questions.id = answers.question_id
                                          JOIN users
                                               on users.id = answers.user_id
                                          WHERE questions.question_active = 1 and 
                                                answers.answer_active = 1
```

And Now i have got one more table named upvote_answers. This table basically stores upvote, downvote for an answer by a user.

if a user has upvoted an answer i.e Columns are user_id, answer_id, upvote (1 or 0 - upvote or downvote respectively)

So my question is i want to get one more coulmn with a boolean result that should show upvoted or downvoted or nothing for each answer for current logged in user

I tried writing like this

```
SELECT answers.answer_content as answer_content,
       answers.id as answer_id,
       answers.created_at as created_at,
       questions.id as question_id, 
       questions.question_title as question_title, 
       questions.question_slug as question_slug, 
       users.id as user_id, 
       users.name as user_name, 
       users.user_slug as user_slug,
       (SELECT count(upvote_answers.answer_id) from upvote_answers, answers WHERE upvote_answers.user_id = 2 and answers.id = upvote_answers.answer_id) as upvotedOrNot
                                  FROM answers
                                          JOIN questions
                                               on questions.id = answers.question_id
                                          JOIN users
                                               on users.id = answers.user_id
                                          WHERE questions.question_active = 1 and 
                                                answers.answer_active = 1
```

when User loggs in he should be able to see if he has upvoted or downvoted an answer or not.

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years.

Comment: Well , I thought i would get relevent commet

Comment: The relevant comment is to use a `JOIN`. This makes things *considerably* easier.

Comment: Okay i will, this worked this is why i didnt thought about proper JOIN statement, But please can u help me with my problem

Comment: Maybe if you post your query with `JOIN` syntax, many more people will try to help you.

Comment: Okay Eric, will do

Comment: can u guys have a look. I have edited